# Show data only when it matches a search

Tags: html, jquery

I have a search with filter that narrows down data as expected. I would like to implement the functionality of hiding all the data by default, and only show results when they match a search. At the moment if nothing is typed everything is shown. The list will be very long once all data will be added, hence the request. Many thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-box").on("keyup", function() {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      var filter = $('#search-filter').val().toLowerCase();
      if(filter == "listitem") {
        $(".listitem").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      } else {
        $(".td-"+filter).filter(function() {
          $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      }
    });
    $('#search-filter').on("change",function(){
      var value = $("#search-box").val().toLowerCase();
      var filter = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      if(filter == "listitem") {
        $(".listitem").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      } else {
        $(".td-"+filter).filter(function() {
          $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <select id="search-filter" name="search-filter">
        <!--<option value="listitem">All</option>-->
        <option value="" disabled selected>Search by</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="surname">Surname</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input id="search-box" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Type here..." required="required"/>
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead> 
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="listitem">
        <td class="td-name">Jane</td>
        <td class="td-surname">Doe</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="listitem">
        <td class="td-name">Dela</td>
        <td class="td-surname">Cruz</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `.filter()`? You should use `.each()` to loop over all the elements in a collection.

Comment: If the search box is empty, just hide all the items and skip the loop that toggles based on the search field.

Comment: @Barmar how does that look like? I don't know how to code it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by hiding everything. Then use an `if` statement to test if the search value is not empty, and show the matching elements.

I've also pulled the filtering code out into a named function, so we don't have to repeat it in both event listeners.

`.filter()` shouldn't be used to execute operations on each element, that should be done with `.each()`. But in this case you can use it to return a new collection that's just the matching elements, and you can then show them all together.

```js
function filter_items(value, filter) {
  $(".listitem, thead").hide();
  if (value != '') {
    if (filter == "listitem") {
      $(".listitem").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(value)
      }).show();
    } else {
      $(".td-" + filter).filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(value)
      }).closest(".listitem").show();
    }
    if ($(".listitem:visible").length > 0) {
      $("thead").show();
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-box").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var filter = $('#search-filter').val().toLowerCase();
    filter_items(value, filter);
  });
  $('#search-filter').on("change", function() {
    var value = $("#search-box").val().toLowerCase();
    var filter = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    filter_items(value, filter);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <select id="search-filter" name="search-filter">
        <!--<option value="listitem">All</option>-->
        <option value="" disabled selected>Search by</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="surname">Surname</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input id="search-box" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Type here..." required="required" />
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="listitem">
        <td class="td-name">Jane</td>
        <td class="td-surname">Doe</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="listitem">
        <td class="td-name">Dela</td>
        <td class="td-surname">Cruz</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to also have the `<th>` headings to disappear when there are no results? Might be difficult though

Comment: I've managed to show/hide the `<th>` with the results using a class, but I'm doing something wrong because it's also considering the text of the headings when searching. They shouldn't be considered in the search. Any help please? Many thanks

Comment: Hide `thead` when you hide all the list items. Then after filtering, do `if ($(".listitem:visible").length > 0) { $("thead").show; }`

Comment: Where is "after filtering"? Sorry I'm bad at this. Thank you

Comment: The code inside `if (value != '')` does the filtering. So put it at the end of that `if` block.

Comment: Can't make it work.. I'm probably putting it in the wrong place.

Comment: Amazing thank you!